# Git push rejected and fetch failed

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am working on my own branch and I have a problem with pushing my last commit.

1) Previously I commited some changes with wrong commit message and updated the commit message by git commit --ammend command.

Now I am able to see this commits on git repository on my branch with previous commited message. (message before ammending)

2) Now I am  commited another changes and when I want to push it, I see previous ammended commit is on the push list in addition to my current commits.

But I am not able to push them, git says I need to merge them but when I click merge, it says me :

> 17:41 Fetch failed: there are still refs under
>   'refs/remotes/origin/mybr'
>
> 17:41 Push rejected: Push was rejected, and update failed with error.

I have no idea where mybr comes from actually. It is not my branch which I am working on.

How can I fix this problem what is wrong ?

Comment: Please quote the exact error message. Copy and paste it in here: don't type it incorrectly as you are doing.

Comment: The fact that you made a change after pushing suggests to me that you are just missing the `--force` flag to `git push` to tell it to overwrite the commit with the bad commit message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as Tyler points out, the history you're trying to push to the remote doesn't match the remote history of the branch since you rewrote a commit which is now absent in *your* new history.

**IF** this is a feature branch on which you're alone to work, just tell git you *do* want to push this history even if it doesn't match the current one :

```
git push --force <remoteName> <branchName>
```

If in the other hand you share the branch with people, it would **NOT** be the way to go. But I guess you would have said so.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you create a new branch at the location of the hash which was functioning correctly followed by copying the files to this new branch and committing and pushing those to origin

After that force your branch onto the new branch and delete the new branch. That should get things going smoothly